# is textScaleFactor render a responsive text?

Tags: flutter, responsiveness

i have two questions.

**first:**

using `textScaleFactor` make text responsive according to the device font size, is not it?

**second:**

what is the difference between using `textScaleFactor of MediaQuery` and using `textScaleFactor` of Text Property.

**MediaQuery Code:**

```
MediaQuery(
           child: Text( "I Will Read 10 pages of my book."),
           data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.5)),
),
```

**Text Code:**

```
Text(
      "I Will Read 10 pages of my book.",
       textScaleFactor: 1.2,
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question, you are right. `textScaleFactor` basically overwrites the device's font size.

**MediaQuery**- provides MediaQueryData to its descendants (means data effect the whole child widget -like you use multiple texts in a column, all text data changed based on MediaQuery data )

But if you use `textScaleFactor` and you need to change font size then you would change it from your devices.

```
MediaQuery(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text("I Will Read 10 pages of my book."),
                  Text("I Will Read 6 pages of my book.")
                ],
              ),
              data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.5)),
          Text(
            "I Will Read 10 pages of my book.",
            textScaleFactor: 1.2,
          ),
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: is there is another case using  MediaQuery? @Jahidul Islam

Comment: definitely, it uses also a different approach. I added code and a screenshot please have a look for a better understanding